Refactor this repetition that can lead to a stack overflow for large inputs. I am just checking 2 words are alpha numeric. Any guidance?
"SETTINGS.(?:(\w+\.)+METHOD\d+)"; Refactor this repetition that can lead to a stack overflow for large inputs.
Solution for "SETTINGS.(?:(\w+\.)+METHOD\d+)"; Refactor this repetition that can lead to a stack overflow for large inputs.
